# How to deal with properties that are initilaized asynchronously in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get an AngularFirestoreCollection from a service in angular. The AngularFirestoreCollection is initialized asynchronously inside an observable subscription. When I try to get the collection from a component, I get an error because it is undefined.

Here is the code for my service:

```
fokosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Foko>;
myFokos: Observable<Foko[]>;

constructor(auth: AuthService, public afs: AngularFirestore) {

  this.myFokos = auth.user$.switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.fokosCollection = afs.collection<Foko>('users/' + user.uid + '/fokos');
      return this.fokosCollection.valueChanges();
    }
  });

}
```

This is the code of my component:

```
 this.myListService.fokosCollection.doc(codeInput).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(foko => {
   getData(foko)
 });
```

I tried make a Subject that notified the component when the Collection was initialized. This worked when I navigated directly to this component. However, if I navigated to this component from another, the subject subscription was never called (because the subscription did not exist when the Subject emitted the collection).

Here is what I tried:

```
fokosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Foko>;
fokosCollectionSubject = new Subject<AngularFirestoreCollection<Foko>>();
myFokos: Observable<Foko[]>;

constructor(auth: AuthService, public afs: AngularFirestore) {

  this.myFokos = auth.user$.switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.fokosCollection = afs.collection<Foko>('users/' + user.uid + '/fokos');
      this.fokosCollectionSubject.next(this.fokosCollection);
      ...
```

And I changed the code of the component to this:

```
this.myListService.fokosCollectionSubject.take(1).switchMap(fokosCollection => {
    return fokosCollection.doc(codeInput).valueChanges().take(1);
  }).subscribe(foko => {
    getData(foko)
  });
```

I can try to get the Collection and if it throws an error, subscribe to the Subject. However, I think that would not be good code. So, what is the best practice to deak with asynchronous data in Angular?

Comment: You pasted the same code twice.

Comment: No, if you look carefully, you see that I have a subject that passes the collection on the second code snippet

Comment: Ok, you could add just the difference to make it easy to understand for readers. Can you share your component code ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @bygrace I get "cannot find method doc of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `switchMap` you are not returning a value if user is falsy. You should return something. Using the `filter` operator prevents that case.

Since you want to know when `fokosCollection` is initialized I would suggest that you expose it as an observable.

```
fokosCollection: Observable<AngularFirestoreCollection<Foko>>;
myFokos: Observable<Foko[]>;

constructor(auth: AuthService, public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.fokosCollection = auth.user$
    .filter(x => x != null)
    .map(user => afs.collection<Foko>('users/' + user.uid + '/fokos'))
    .shareReplay(1);
  this.myFokos = this.fokosCollection.switchMap(x => x.valueChanges());
}
```

I added `shareReplay(1)` to share a single underlying subscription and to replay the last value to new subscribers. You may or may not want this in your scenario but I find that I generally want it when exposing observables that could have multiple subscriptions.

Then in your component:

```
this.myListService.fokosCollection.switchMap(x => x.doc(codeInput).valueChanges()).take(1).subscribe(foko => {
   getData(foko)
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not include fokosCollection

Comment: @SondreSørbye it has it as an observable. Since you wanted to know when it was initialized.

Comment: This does not work because switchMap must return an observable, fokosCollection is of type AngularFirestoreCollection.

Comment: @SondreSørbye Sorry, I am not very familiar with FireBase. I switched it to a `map`. I also switched `myFokos` and the component code to use a `switchMap` since `valueChanges()` returns an observable.

Comment: @SondreSørbye I saw your suggested edit. Adding the `shareReplay(1)` would be better in the service so that other consumers will not create additional subscriptions. For instance, subscribing to `myFokos` would create another subscription down the to root since the `shareReplay(1)` isn't in its stream. I'll update the answer to have the share and replay in the service.